# Is there a way to transpose all CSV column values on top of rows, with pandas, python, or excel? (column 1 = row 1, column 2 = row 2)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I need to take every column of my csv file, and set it as the row, since every value at (x,y) is the same at (y,x). Seems easy, but I keep getting errors.
[Image of one-sided data along horizonal][1]
I have tried parsing with df.iat, and several other pandas methods, including iloc, turning the column into a list object, then trying to set the list object at an indexed row, transpose (both in python via pandas, and excel for time)

````
    # Set to 5 just to verify that it does not erase old data, but adds new
    # true range is 10,000 x 10,000
    for x in range(1,5):
        for y in range(x+1,5):
            a = float(toParse.iat[y,x])
            toParse.iat[x,y] = a

# Data beforehand 
data = {'1': [None,None,None,None,None],
        '2': ['0.6',None,None,None,None],
        '3': ['0.93','1.01',None,None,None],
        '4': ['0.22','0.124','.134',None,None],
        '5': ['0.77','0.012','0.232','0.99',None]}   

# After transposed
data = {'1': [None,'0.6','0.93','0.22','0.77'],
        '2': ['0.6',None,'1.01','0.124','0.012'],
        '3': ['0.93','1.01',None,'0.134','0.232'],
        '4': ['0.22','0.124','0.134',None,'0.99'],
        '5': ['0.77','0.012','0.232','0.99',None]}```
````

Comment: quite a few ways you could tackle this in Pandas - what would be useful is a textual example of your dataframe (5 rows will do) and an example output (again 5 rows) in terms of tranposing in pandas, you can call the `df.T` method

Comment: I'll write out the example right now, but I used df.T, and it just concatenated columns beside each other, so I ended up with 10 columns with 2x duplicate data instead of them being set as rows. I'll add the next comment as example. Pretty new to writing in Stack Overflow.

Comment: No problem might need to use `pd.melt`

Comment: I added the code to the original for easier viewing. I'll go look into the Pandas Docs on melt while waiting

Comment: Essentially, all I want to do is take column one, and set row one to all it's values (It's a square set), then column 2, etc. through column 10,000.

Comment: If I do `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`(with data from the "Data beforehand") is that the starting point of your question, and you need to get to what it looks like after?

Comment: Yes, I actually just forgot to write the putting it in a df part, in the visualization. There's some way to set a column to an object, then apply it to a row one by one, I just never solved it. I actually reran the entire algorithm (3 hour process) to get it. I do hope, out of curiosity, to find the answer though.

Comment: So, for whomever may benefit from this later: I was able to transpose my data, but lost the other side and couldn't merge them well (not time-efficiently anyway). The ways I solved this was rerunning and storing correctly. The way to fix it in (n^2)/2 -n time was to invert my loops and write backwards, from only the other half of the horizontal, cell by cell. I really would have loved a column-transformed-to-row answer, but was unsuccessful and long parsing won out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To flip it across the diagonal:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1': [None,None,None,None,None],
    '2': ['0.6',None,None,None,None],
    '3': ['0.93','1.01',None,None,None],
    '4': ['0.22','0.124','.134',None,None],
    '5': ['0.77','0.012','0.232','0.99',None]
})

flipped = df.T
flipped.columns = df.columns
flipped.index = df.index

func = lambda col1, col2: col1.combine_first(col2)
df.combine(flipped, func)
```

Original:

```
      1     2     3      4      5
0  None   0.6  0.93   0.22   0.77
1  None  None  1.01  0.124  0.012
2  None  None  None   .134  0.232
3  None  None  None   None   0.99
4  None  None  None   None   None
```

After transformation:

```
      1      2      3      4      5
0  None    0.6   0.93   0.22   0.77
1   0.6   None   1.01  0.124  0.012
2  0.93   1.01   None   .134  0.232
3  0.22  0.124   .134   None   0.99
4  0.77  0.012  0.232   0.99   None
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do! I cannot yet give thumbs up, otherwise I would.